# Infragistics WebDataGrid Reload Refresh

Tags: infragistics

I've recently been using this product.  The support on their site is lacking.  I've implemented a custom search/filtering feature on the server side.  The feature limits the data to only the matching rows.  My issue is how to get the grid to reload or refresh after this operation.

I have tried removing the invalid rows from the grid, creating a new data source for the grid, even creating a new grid all together.  The client side does not show the changes until I click a page forward button.  At that point the grid refreshes and shows my new data.

I've found web references to calling rows.Clear(), grid.ClearDataSource().... no joy.  I've looked at client side JS as well.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
ST

Answer (score 1):

You could use the WebDataGrid filtering on the client.  There is an example of how to do this on the Infragistics here: http://blogs.infragistics.com/forums/p/24061/88728.aspx#88728